# Send utf-8 request to translator using python

Tags: python, azure, unicode, python-requests

I've messing with a piece of code.

I'm trying to send sentences in different languages to microsoft azure translator using python, but I can't make utf-8 work.

I spend many times look all over internet or asking into chat, so since i'm stuck, here I am.

I'm using jupyter so here it is :

```
import requests

url="https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com//detect?api-version=3.0"

params = (
    ('Subscription-Key', cle),
)

token = requests.post('https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken', params=params)
token.text
```

It's use to generate the token for Microsoft Azure, it works properly.

```
import json
import codecs

paragraphe='シャーリー・フィールドは、サ'
paragraphe
```

My sentence, I import json for later, and codecs when i was trying to do utf-8

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token.text,
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region': 'northeurope',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '[{\'Text\':\'' + paragraphe + '\'}]'
#data = '[{\'Text\':\'\u30B7\u30E3\u30FC\u30EA\u30FC\u30FB\u30D5\u30A3\u30FC\u30EB\u30C9\u306F\u3001\u30B5\'}]'
#data = { 'Text' : paragraphe }

reponse = requests.post('https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com//detect?api-version=3.0', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
```

This is where is goes wrong, if I use a sentence like "hello how are you ?" it works perfectly, but as soon as I use special letters, I got :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 10-23: Body ('シャーリー・フィールドは、サ') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

I believe this is a simple problem, but I need some help.

Also if I use something like this :

```
data = json.dumps({'Text': "シャーリー・フィールドは、サ"}).encode('utf-8')
```

I get

```
'{"error":{"code":400074,"message":"The body of the request is not valid JSON."}}'
```

In reponse.text

Many thanks.

Comment: When sending JSON data with `requests`, one usually uses `requests.post(..., json=data)`, where data is a "jsonable" Python structure (typically a dict). – The UnicodeEncodeError looks like it might be coming from a print statement (check the line number in the traceback). – I don't think `json.dumps` ever produces invalid JSON, but maybe the server is unhappy about the schema (eg. it doesn't expect an array/list at the top level, but rather an object/dict).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
data=[{
"text":"シャーリー・フィールドは、サ"
}]

reponse = requests.post('https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/detect?api-version=3.0', headers=headers, data=str(data).encode('utf-8'))

print(reponse.text);
```

Result:

[image]

Pls let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: This is definitely the way to do it. I don't know why me and others didn't figure out this. Many thanks.

I guess it's because I never have a problem with Unicode before..

Fun fact is, if I'm using the Text Analytics instead of Translator (still from Azure), I don't need any encoding at all. And it works exactly the same. Still a mystery !

Anyway, many thanks to you for spending time on this answer. :)

Comment: @Max ,Welcome, gald to know it is helpful!

Comment: @StanleyGong but `str(data)` does not produce valid JSON. For example, it will use single quotes instead of double most of the time.